# create class with functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

is there a way to create a class with functions to be called from other scripts throughout the page once loaded?

```
function WebUI() {
    this.updateLoadingMessage = function (message) {
        $("#loading-header").html(message);
    };

    addAlertInfo = function (message) {
    };

    addAlertWarning = function (message) {
    };

    addAlertDanger = function (message) {
    };

    addAlertSuccess = function (message) {
    };
};
```

Call from other places/scripts

```
WebUI.addAlertInfo("testing");
```

Tells me that addAlertInfo is not a function.

Comment: Please clarify the expected result, perhaps with an example.

Comment: I want to house a bunch of common functions within one call that I can call upon from any other script.

Comment: Are you trying to create an instance as in `var ui = new WebUI(); ui.addAlertInfo("testing")`?  Or just a namespace object were you don't create an instance, but instead just park a bunch of static functions on your WebUI function as properties?  What you have now is neither.

Comment: @jfriend00 namespace object where I don't have to create an instance.

Comment: Then, why do you have a `WebUI` constructor function defined.  That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @jfriend00 wasn't exactly sure what I was doing lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close. See "Defining methods" at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects. You can do something like:

```
WebUI = {
    addAlertInfo: function(message) {
         // do stuff
    }
};
```

Comment: Except they also have a WebUI constructor defined too.  Not clear what the OP wants.

Comment: @jfriend00 Fair enough. I'd personally handle that by giving the WebUI object an `init` function and call `WebUI.init()` in the page or in the JS after `WebUI` is defined.

Comment: Thank you this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this a number of ways: A few that come to mind, are:

```
var WebUI = {
    addAlertInfo: function() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Or as a method on a function that might act as a constructor:

```
function WebUI() {
    ...
}

WebUI.addAlertInfo = function () {
}
```

Or in ES6:

```
class WebUI {
    static addAlertInfo() {
        ...
    }
}
```

All of these would be called like:

```
WebUI.addAlertInfo();
```

Answer (score 0):

Among many ways , the two most easiest way of doing so is either using [**namespacing**](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/12/07/namespacing-in-javascript/) or [**Revealing-module-pattern**](https://carldanley.com/js-revealing-module-pattern/)

Here is an example of using namespacing.
You first create an empty object

```
var WebUI ={};
WebUI.addAlertInfo=function(){
 // Rest of the code
}
```

Now you can call `WebUI.addAlertInfo()` from anywhere else